# which editor is used in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, editor

Which editor is used in wordpress? I need one editor something like wordpress used.
Please give me some good editors.

Comment: What do you mean by editor? Javascript "rich" text editor?

Comment: wordpress is open source, isn't it?

Answer (score 11):

WordPress uses the [TinyMCE](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE) editor by Moxiecode Systems:

> WordPress is bundled with the open source HTML WYSIWYG editor TinyMCE by Moxiecode Systems, AB.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (formerly FCKEditor) It is pretty stable, mature, and compatible.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor):

> CKEditor is compatible with most Internet browsers, including: Internet Explorer 5.5+ (Windows), Firefox 1.5+, Safari 3.0+, Google Chrome (Windows), Opera 9.50+, and Camino 1.0+ (Apple).